# .htaccess and SSL and redirect to index.php

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I have this .htaccess file to redirect all request to index.php in the root.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|pl|txt)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
```

Now I want to add to force http protocol to https.

How I must change my file?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correctly switching between HTTP and HTTPS using .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108706/correctly-switching-between-http-and-https-using-htaccess)

Comment: thanks for your support, but i think that my problem is different or probably i don't understand the solution of your post.

Comment: Have you read that post, and tried including the solution from that post into your htaccess file? If not, do so - the solution is there.

Comment: Sorry but i don't know to apply the solution on my case. I'm newbie of .htaccess. I have tried to add 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https:// index.php [R=301,L]
but it does not work

Comment: In addition, to these rewrite rules, note that rewrite rules are not sufficient to make your site secure. The redirection from HTTP to HTTPS only happens once the client has already made a (plain text) HTTP connection, for each connection. You should make sure that, once your user have reached the HTTPS side of your site, they stay on it (all subsequent links within your site should point to the HTTPS addresses, not HTTP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to force all requests to your domain to be secure, then add the code below to your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#if the request is not secure
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#redirect to the secure version
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#These are your existing rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|pl|txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
```