# htacess rewrite rule work on IE but not on firefox and chrome

Tags: apache

I have this re-write rule on apache and working perfectly redirect to the site I want on ie but not on firefox or chrome. and I am wondering why acting differently on theses browsers??!!

this is my apache rewrite config

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteLog "/opt/apache/logs/rewrite.log"
  RewriteLogLevel 1
  RewriteCond     %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://server/index.php [L,R]
```

so the apache rule properly redirect to "https://server/index.php but on Firefox/chrome stop at "https://server". is there any mistake on my apache re-write configration?

thanks.

Comment: Browsers don't have rewrite rules. Check with wireshark what is being sent, and give us more details.

Comment: thanks for the response but not understand what you mean.I didn't say the browser rewrite. this is apache config. and the site properly re-direct. as said it's working just fine with ie. my question is why Firefox not re-direct propelry.so would you tell me the role of wireshark .

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1128624/913097). Also, clean the cache in your browsers.

Comment: thanks clean the browser did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clean the  Firefox/chrome  cache and try it again. may be old information on browser conflict with new redirect.

Answer (score 0):

**The browsers dont redirect and dont do redirects.
Web server does redirects.**
Browser has nothing to do with it, wether it is Firefox, IE, Safari or whatever.

Comment: I agree. however my question is about my apache configuration not about the browser because the configuration acting diferently on different borwser.

Comment: It could be that Firefox / Chrome just cut off the "index.php" part of your url.
However, as long as you only have one index.* file in your https:// folder, this shouldn't affect the outcome.
You will still see the same output.