# Update DNS with SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, dns

everytime I go to our current site  www.example.com or  example.com   I would like it to redirect to  https://www.example.com   .. should I do this via DNS  (if so how? do i add a new a name or cname  record)  or do I need to do this in the apache configurations?

Thanks

Comment: No, DNS doesn't handle this. Look at using htaccess for redirecting the user.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108706/correctly-switching-between-http-and-https-using-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess file, in the folder you wish to redirect from.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```