# redirection issue in Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have enabled https and can navigate application using HTTP and HTTPS without rewrite. Apache 2.2.24. But I see a strange behavior:

Receiving `400 bad request` if passing `http://hostname.com/XXX` but works fine with `url/xxx/` Don’t know how `/` can help to redirect to https.

Also, enabled the rewrite with following in `httpd.conf` but don’t see a difference.
Also, HTTP redirection is not working.

**Rewrite Engine**

```
RewriteEngine On
```

now the **rewriting rules**

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://hostname.com/XXX [R,L]`
```

Comment: Try replacing your condition with `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off`.

Comment: A related one: [Correctly switching between HTTP and HTTPS using .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1108706/2157640)

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way to do that is to make 2 virtualhosts, one listening on IP:80 (HTTP) redirecting to HTTPS and the other listening on IP:443 (HTTPS).

```
<VirtualHost private_ip_of_your_server:80>
    ServerName www.mywebsite.com

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache/http_www_mywebsite_com_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache/http_www_mywebsite_com_access.log combined

    RedirectPermanent / https://www.mywebsite.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost private_ip_of_your_server:443>
    ServerName www.mywebsite.com

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache/https_www_mywebsite_com_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache/https_www_mywebsite_com_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to add the two associated NameVirtualHost directives:
 - NameVirtualHost private_ip_of_your_server:80
 - NameVirtualHost private_ip_of_your_server:443

Regards