# .htaccess redirect from http://www.domain/ to https://domain.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can I (with a htaccess file) redirect a page that looks like this:

```
http://www.domain/page/?var=test&var2=test2
```

To something that looks like this:

```
 https://domain/page/?var=test&var2=test2
```

But do it so it only affects this page and nothing else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect to https://www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1128624/2057919). You want something like this:

```
# Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS, but only if the requested page is /page
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^page/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an `[OR]` between 2 rewrite conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(page(?:/.*)?)$ https://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

This will redirect to `https://domain.com` if HTTPS is off OR else if your host name is `www.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```