# apache HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto in .htaccess is causing redirect loop in dev environment

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've had to update my .htaccess from this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

to get it working behind an AWS Elasic Load Balancer.

It all seems to work fine on AWS, but in my local environment I'm stuck in a redirect loop.

How I can get this setup to work correctly in both environments?

Comment: Are you running your local Apache server as a reverse proxy/load balancer? Have you set `RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"` in your local VirtualHost configuration?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

To make it work in both environments you can combine both conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: This actually works without the [OR], but with it it causes the redirect loop.

Comment: This works for my homepage `http://www.ex.com redirects to https` but if somebody goes to a direct page ``http://www.ex.com/about` doesn't redirect to https. I am behind an AWS load balancer

Comment: You are the winner bro!!

Comment: Just make sure that, if you using loadbalancer, you getting X-Forwarded-Proto

Comment: What's the NE (noescape) flag for in this case please?

Answer (score 2):

I had a special case for a shared hosting (masterhost), everything was failing except:

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Port} !443
  RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```