# Redirect all traffic to SSL except some domains

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl

We are currently using the following code to redirect traffic to SSL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.duplika.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that parked domains like www.duplika.net or www.duplika.com.br are also redirected to https://www.duplika.com.

Is there a way to redirect traffic, except the ones from this domains?

After looking at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108706/correctly-switching-between-http-and-https-using-htaccess), I've tried the following without success:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^br.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^net.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.duplika.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to match on `%{HTTP_HOST}` to filter out the domains

```php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.(net|br)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.duplika.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The above example tests that a domain does not end with `.net` or `.br` before redirecting. You might need to change the pattern based on all the domains you don't want to be redirected.